# How to automatically rename music files?

Tags: youtube, music, m4a

I have around 700 audio songs in .m4a format which I downloaded from YouTube, but they are named as videoplayback.m4a. Is there any way they can be given proper titles automatically?

All are famous songs with millions of views on YouTube. I was thinking of some music recognition site or software which can be automated to do this task.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Are the files tagged? i.e. do they have the track info in the m4a metadata?

Comment: I am running windows 7, no the files have no track info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) to tag and rename your files. It uses a matching algorithm which should be able to identify most of the songs and is free and open source software.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Pickard is really an amazing software, exactly what I needed. It worked good with mp3 files, but when I try with m4a files it detects the correct tags but is unable to rename them.It says 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment.
 Below is the error log:

Comment: E: 12:16:25 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "picard\util\thread.pyo", line 46, in run
  File "picard\file.pyo", line 116, in _load_check
  File "picard\formats\mp4.pyo", line 121, in _load
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

E: 12:16:38 Network request error for https://coverartarchive.org:443/release/dae2044d-3071-4fec-a663-637dc611edcf/: SSL handshake failed (QT code 6, HTTP code None)
E: 12:16:38 CAA JSON error: SSL handshake failed

Comment: I have not personally used Picard with M4A files; however, they are listed as an officially supported file type so they should work in the same way as MP3 files. It looks like your error may be related to trying to add/save cover art as part of the tag. For now at least I would suggest disabling the cover art tagging.